# How to create dynamic array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have an array like

```
{
  "Count": 3,
  "Items": [
    {
      "prod_price": {
        "N": "100"
      },
      "prod_name": {
        "S": "Laptop"
      },
      "prod_Id": {
        "N": "3"
      }
    },
    {
      "prod_price": {
        "N": "1000"
      },
      "prod_name": {
        "S": "Mouse"
      },
      "prod_Id": {
        "N": "2"
      }
    },
    {
      "prod_price": {
        "N": "2000"
      },
      "prod_name": {
        "S": "Keyboard"
      },
      "prod_Id": {
        "N": "1"
      }
    }
  ],
  "ScannedCount": 3
}
```

I need the output like

```
{
  "Count": 3,
  "Items": [
    {
      "prod_price" : "100",
      "prod_name": "Laptop",
      "prod_Id":  "3"
    },
    {
      "prod_price" : "1000",
      "prod_name": "mouse",
      "prod_Id":  "2"
    },
    {
      "prod_price" : "2000",
      "prod_name": "keyboard",
      "prod_Id":  "1"
    },

  ],
  "ScannedCount": 3
}
```

I am trying to get this output but no able to get this can you help me for this.

```
var items=data['Items'];
        var itemresult={};
        itemvalues={};


    for(var attributename in items){

        for(var itemattribute in items[attributename]){

            for(var key in items[attributename][itemattribute]){

              console.log(itemvalues);
              itemresult.attributename.itemattribute=items[attributename][itemattribute][key];

            }

        }
```

I am new to *node.js* and don't how to work with the *for loops* exactly.
I have tried my best, as if in *php* we have the *for-each* loop so we can skip the index value.

If I can get that so this conversion will be done. I don't know how to get that, can you please help me to find the solution?

I know there can be some problem because I don't know the exact syntax so any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: why just not to use Array.map, it's both browser/nodejs; or some of the https://lodash.com/ toolbox

Comment: As a note: This is not related to node but a regular JavaScript question (I know this is somehow nit picking, but you should always be clear about what it language and what it platform specific) . Beside that you should take care what kind of loop you use for which kind of object. [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var items = data['Items'];

var result = [];
items.forEach(function(item) {
  result.push({
    prod_price: item.prod_price.N,
    prod_name: item.prod_name.S,
    prod_Id: item.prod_Id.N
  });
});
```

Optionally you could use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var result = items.map(function(item) {
  return {
    prod_price: item.prod_price.N,
    prod_name: item.prod_name.S,
    prod_Id: item.prod_Id.N
  };
});
```

Comment: It should be noted that this is only working in environments that support ES5 [Array#forEach or Array#map](http://caniuse.com/#search=foreach)

Comment: @vanhelgen Yep. The question is tagged Node so I think he'll be OK. Well worth pointing out, though.

Comment: Ahh, fair enough. I glanced over this - but at least it's not wrong *g*